A child who will not talk who lives in an institution
Two years ago, I saw this show and I think it was a recent episode. In it there was some kind of institution and in this institution there was a little boy. I think the whole place might have been for children but I'm not sure. The boy is about eight I think and he won't talk though, I think later in the episode he starts talking to which is very shocking for the other characters. At one point the boy's very concerned father comes to visit and the boy will not talk to him either. At one point the boy rolls a dinky car under the locked door of a room in the institution that no one enters and is supposedly empty. In the room I think a child died in though the episode isn't very clear on what the bad thing that happened in it was. At the end of the episode the car rolls out from under the locked door. 
I think the show was American though I am also not sure about that.

The show is called Touch
Official Synopsis: May contain spoiler.

A preternatural drama in which science and spirituality intersect with
  the hopeful premise that we are all interconnected, tied in invisible
  ways to those whose lives we are destined to alter and impact. Through
  masterful storytelling, the series follows a group of seemingly
  unrelated characters, beginning with a former firefighter tormented by
  his inability to save a dying woman, an Iraqi teenager who will go to
  great risks to help his family, a gifted singer whose actions at a
  karaoke bar save lives thousands of miles away, and a British
  businessman desperately trying to retrieve a key piece of information
  from his lost mobile phone, who affect each other in ways seen and
  unseen. At the center is Martin Bohm (Sutherland), a widower and
  single father, haunted by an inability to connect to his mute
  10-year-old son, Jake. Caring, intelligent and thoughtful, Martin has
  tried everything to reach his son, who shows little emotion and never
  allows himself to be touched by anyone, including Martin. Jake busies
  himself with cast-off cell phones, disassembling them and manipulating
  the parts, allowing him to see the world in his own special way. After
  multiple failed attempts at keeping Jake in school, Martin is visited
  by social worker Clea Hopkins, who insists on doing an evaluation of
  the Bohms' living situation. Although new at her job, Clea sees a man
  whose life has become dominated by a child he can no longer control.
  She believes his attempts to communicate with Jake are just wish
  fulfillment, and determines that it's time for the state to intervene.
  But everything changes when Martin discovers that Jake possesses a
  gift of staggering genius -- the ability to see things that no one
  else can, the patterns that connect everything. Jake is indeed
  communicating after all. But it's not with words, it's with numbers.
  And now he needs Martin to decipher their meaning and connect these
  numbers to the cast of seemingly unrelated characters whose lives they
  affect. Along the way, Martin will be guided by Boris Podolsky, a
  discredited aging professor who offers Martin a compelling but
  unorthodox theory about Jake and his rare ability. Whether it be
  chance, coincidence, timing, synergy or fate, there are events that
  touch us all, as part of an interconnected, dazzlingly precise
  universe.

